# How to make UILabel fits its blue frame

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Is there any way to change padding/margin of `UILabel` in interface builder in `Xcode 8`?

[image]

I'd like to change the blue frame, so it fits "13" without this top/bottom padding.

I need it to set my contraints without any "magic" numbers to make "distance" label touch "13"

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?? If so show the constraints used?

Comment: yes I do, see my edit

Comment: Put a height constraint on the '13' label and adjust its constant so that the distance touches 13

Comment: But I want it to be resizable so height constraint does not sound like a good solution in this case

Comment: Don't add any height/width constraint to the label. It will take the intrinsic size i.e. size according to the text.

Comment: All i want to achieve is set bottom space from "distance" to "13" to 0 and see they stick to each other, but this blue frame creates the distance between them

Answer (score 0):

What i would do, is set the label height equal to the view height, judging from your screenshots should be ~0.3 .